# Change of variables on triangular region.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

> Given an integral $$\iint\limits_\triangle f(x,y) ~dx~dy$$
> switch the variables to polar coordinates, where $\triangle = \{\text{Triangle whose vertices are at } (1,0),(0,2),(5,3)\}$

### **Please see the edit at the bottom**

(Attached the hand drawn figure below).

I'm taking the substitution $$x = 1 + r\cos\theta, \qquad y = r\sin\theta$$
that is a circle centred at $(1,0)$. As shown in the figure, one can fill one part of triangle with circles (say the part $\Omega_1$).

- In $\Omega_1$, we have
  $$0 \le r \le \frac{7}{\sqrt{26}}$$
  (where $|AH|=\frac{7}{\sqrt{26}})$ and
  $$\arctan \frac 34 \le \theta \le \pi - \arctan 2$$
  that is the range of angle between the sides $AB$ and $AC$.
  $$\iint\limits_{\Omega_1} f(x,y)~dx~dy = \int\limits_{\arctan \frac 34}^{\pi - \arctan 2} d\theta \int\limits_{0}^{7/\sqrt{26}} f(1+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)|J|dr$$
  Well, $\Omega_1$ is done.
- Now let $\Omega_2$ be the unfilled region with circles which contains the point $B$ (upper-right region) and $\Omega_3$ be the unfilled region with circles which contains the point $C$ (upper-left region).
- While dealing with these regions, however, $r$ and $\theta$ seems to be "dynamic" in the sense that their bounds are dependent to the other variable.
- I'm not sure how to proceed.

> [image]

---

### Edit:

With the following new figure, I seem to have a better approach.

Then $$\iint\limits_\triangle f(x,y) ~dx~dy = \int_{\arctan(3/4)}^{\pi-\arctan(2)} d\theta \int_0^{7/(5\sin\theta - \cos\theta)} f(1+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)r ~dr$$
since $$BC: y = \frac{1}{5}x+2 \\
\implies r\sin\theta = \frac15(r\cos\theta + 1) + 2 \\
\implies r = \frac{7}{5\sin\theta - \cos\theta}$$
Is it correct?

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your revised approach is correct but you have made some mistakes in your bounds.

[image]

If we use substitution in polar coordinates as, $x = 1 + r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ (in essence we shift the origin to $(1,0)$) -

Measuring the radial distance ($r$) from point $A$, $r$ is bound above by line segment $BC \ (5y-x=10)$ whereas angle $\theta$ is bound between line segments $AB \ (3x-4y = 3)$ and $AC \ (2x + y = 2)$.

$5y -x = 10 \implies 5r\sin\theta - (1 + r\cos\theta) = 10$

That gives upper bound of $r = \dfrac{11}{5\sin\theta - \cos\theta}$

You found the bounds of $\theta$ correctly.

So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_{\arctan(3/4)}^{\pi - \arctan(2)} \int_0^{11/(5\sin\theta - \cos\theta)} f(1+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) \ r \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: Oh, I made a calculation error while finding $r$. Thank you for your thoughts. May I ask one more question? How can I prove that this integral really covers the region fully?

Comment: Because you are taking $A$ as the pivot and taking radial distance from $A$ to points on line $5y-x=10$ for angles between the other two lines. If you take this integral without the function, it should give you the area of the triangle and it does. You can confirm that.

Comment: Thank you @MathLover, I really appreciate your constant help and contribution. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome and very impressive work, in the way you drew the diagram and approached the problem!

Comment: With your help I am learning better!